# cocos2dx android crash upon Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, facebook-android-sdk

I am integrating Facebook SDK for Android on my cocos2d-x-2.2 app

I call the login function like instructed in the FacebookSDK documentation, I also changed the Cocos2dxGameActivity to singleInstance to support SSO. My login function is as follows:

```
    public void loginToFacebook() {
    JLogger.e(null, "MatchThree.loginToFacebook 0");
    if ( Session.getActiveSession() == null || (!Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) ) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                //
                JLogger.e("Facebook", "loginToFacebook call");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, upon the `openActiveSession` call, the application always crash with the following null pointer exception in native code:

11-18 11:13:37.981: E/cocos2d-x assert(6973): C:/cocos2d-x-2.2/projects/fb-test/proj.android/../../../cocos2dx/platform/android/CCApplication.cpp function:sharedApplication line:60
11-18 11:13:37.981: A/libc(6973): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6994 (Thread-16380)

Does anybody encounter this before?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bug in `Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause()`
whereby it did not check for NULL before calling `applicationDidEnterBackground();`

add this:

```
    if (CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView()) {
        CCApplication::sharedApplication()->applicationDidEnterBackground();
    }
```

and you should be safe...

Check out:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/33956

Comment: Thanks! and for further record, it is this file: $(COCOS2DX_ROOT)/platform/android/jni/Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer.cpp